# Bounding rectangle for a triangle and normalized coordinates

Tags: vector, glsl, rectangles, normals

I'm working on some computer graphic stuff and can't figure out solution to one problem:

I have three points in 3D space, each defined with (x,y,z) tupple. Three points together form a triangle. Let point names be A, B and C, so triangle is ABC.

Now I'd like to form a bounding rectangle such that AC is one of the sides. and point B lies on the opposide side of the rectangle. Now I want to map an arbitrary point (p) within the rectangle to normalized UV coordinates, so:

- U represents how far projection of the point p to AC vector is from A.
- V represents the orthogonal part of the rectangle. A bit hard to explain, but see the picture.

Anyway, I think I'm good with finding U:

```
vec3 AC = vec3(C - A);
vec3 Ap = vec3(p - A);
float u = dot(Ap, AC)/dot(AC, AC);
```

But I can't figure out how to find V.
As I use GLSL, it's more than welcome if the answer will use matrix thingies like dot, cross or anything GLSL has.

[Clarification picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcNhS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `u` for point **B**

```
uB = dot(AB, AC)/dot(AC, AC);
```

Projection of **B** onto `AC`:

```
B' = A + uB * AC / length(AC)
```

Now we have **B'B** vector and can make projections on it similar to projections on AC and calculate `v`